# Как правильно добавлять CSS классы БЭМ-блокам и элементами, связанные с темизацией?

Tags: css, бэм

Кнопка с иконкой, релизованная в соответствии с БЭМ (только не со стандартной схемой именования):

```html
<button class="RegularButton">
  <svg class="RegularButton-Icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M11,7A2,2 0 0,0 9,9V11A2,2 0 0,0 11,13H13V15H9V17H13A2,2 0 0,0 15,15V13A2,2 0 0,0 13,11H11V9H15V7H11M12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2Z" />
  </svg>
  <span class="RegularButton-Lettering">Восстановить справедливость</span>
</button>
```

Теперь допустим, её надо темизовать.
Насколько я знаю, использовать селекторы типа ".Block > .Element" или ".Block .Element" в БЭМ не допускается.
С соблюдением этого условия, решение будет:

```html
<button class="RegularButton RegularButton__LightTheme">
  <svg class="RegularButton-Icon RegularButton-Icon__LightTheme" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M11,7A2,2 0 0,0 9,9V11A2,2 0 0,0 11,13H13V15H9V17H13A2,2 0 0,0 15,15V13A2,2 0 0,0 13,11H11V9H15V7H11M12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2Z" />
  </svg>
  <span class="RegularButton-Lettering RegularButton-Lettering__LightTheme">Восстановить справедливость</span>
</button>
```

Правильно ли с точки методологии БЭМ это решение?

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что _использовать селекторы типа ".Block > .Element" или ".Block .Element" в БЭМ не допускается_?

Comment: @Grundy Насколько я помню (но конечно, я могу ошибаться), в руководстве по БЭМ по меньшей мере не рекомендовалось это делать потому, что эти селекторы сложнее переопределить и они порождают "войну приоритетов".

Comment: @Grundy, а, вот: "Методология БЭМ допускает использование вложенных селекторов, но рекомендует свести их применение к минимуму" ([источник](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/css/#%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)).

Answer (score 1):

Использование вложенных селекторов допускается, но с соблюдением меры:

> Вложенность уместна, если необходимо изменить стили элементов в
>   зависимости от модификатора (например, состояния блока или заданной
>   темы)
>
> [Документация](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/css/#%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)

Таким образом, `RegularButton-Icon__LightTheme` и `RegularButton-Lettering__LightTheme` можно убрать:

```html
<button class="RegularButton RegularButton__LightTheme">
  <svg class="RegularButton-Icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M11,7A2,2 0 0,0 9,9V11A2,2 0 0,0 11,13H13V15H9V17H13A2,2 0 0,0 15,15V13A2,2 0 0,0 13,11H11V9H15V7H11M12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2Z" />
  </svg>
  <span class="RegularButton-Lettering">Восстановить справедливость</span>
</button>
```

Комбинированные же селекторы имеют статус "не рекомендуется":

> Методология БЭМ не рекомендует использовать комбинированные селекторы.
>   Комбинированные селекторы (например, .button.button_theme_islands)
>   имеют более высокую специфичность, чем одиночные селекторы, что
>   усложняет задачу их переопределения.
>
> [Документация](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/css/#%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)